# Notice SMTP connect failed

Tags: joomla-3.x, emails, localhost, smtp

is it possible to send a reset password mail from front end .

I have a joomla web site running on local host . I want user able to reset their password from front end. I try all things like install a hmail server and test mail server. Still not luck.

Every time say notice SMTP connect fail . All the seeting in the global configuration changes acc. to R & D.

Still m=not sending mail.

Any one can help me give me code or configuration or plug in to reset password from front end .

Comment: In your joomla global configuration set these parameters :

`Mailer= SMTP
SMTP Host = smtp.gmail.com,
SMTP Port  = 465
SMTP Username = your gmail id
SMTP Password = and password`

Comment: I already mentioned in post that I already lots of R &  D on this topic I try all the configuration @ nehal

Comment: I assume the use of hMail server means it's a Windows machine.  Please confirm.   Also, I assume the issue is not actually with the SMTP server but the user database behind it (and not even the Joomla user database), so you're looking for either Windows user password reset or hMail user DB password reset - again, please confirm.

Comment: I want that that end user can change the password from front end@MarkBradley

Answer (score 1):

Local hosts do not support emails unless you manually install and configure the required tools, which is quite a fussy task.

Thus, to test your emails, I'd suggest moving your site to a live server instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try define true smtp account data to send your messages. I do this In my site and never more have problems with messages. All components work perfect now.